# Converting a externalInterface call from AS 3 to JS

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, createjs

I have a game I am currently porting over from FLASH/AS3 to Flash(canvas)/JS. In the game I had to make an external interface all to get a number from an outsize source.

```
private function getAwardAmount(e:Event):void {
            var paramObj:Object = this.stage.loaderInfo.parameters;
            totalAmount = paramObj.AwardAmount;

        trace(totalAmount);

        if (totalAmount == null)
        {
            totalAmount = "$240";
        }
            var regExp2:RegExp = /[$]/;
            var cleanString2:String = totalAmount.replace(regExp2,"");
            trace(cleanString2);

        // set the winning string
        winAmount.text = "YOU WON $" + cleanString2 +"!";
    }
```

I'm not 100% sure how to get that same outside call but use it in the create JS interface. I would think that since it's all JS that it would be easier, but nothing I have tried has worked so far.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you confusing ExternalInterface with loader params (as in parameters appended to your SWF path, or in a params attribute in your embed code)? I don't see where you are using ExternalInterface in your code. If you are having trouble getting values from JavaScript functions called in frame scripts, then you probably have a scope issue. Can you post more code?

Comment: Maybe I am? I'm trying to read a property of an object that is loaded externally, with what I assume is the loaderInfo params. How do I use that in a create js environment?

Comment: What are you loading?

Answer (score 0):

`stage.loaderInfo.parameters` is an object that holds name-value pairs that were passed to your SWF from html code through FlashVars and/or query parameters and it has nothing to do with [external interface api](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Since you are porting from flash to javascript, you just don't need to do this anymore. `AwardAmount` variable was already on the html side before you started porting, just look how it was assigned in html/javascript code.

- [loaderInfo.parameters reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters)
- [passing variables from html to SWF](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)